# Allure - i want to change the title of @BeforeClass and @AfterClass methods in Report(I am using TestNG)

Tags: java, selenium, testng, allure

I have installation steps running with `@BeforeClass` annotation before each test.
When these steps are failing, I get BeforeClass title showing up in allure reports.
How can I change this title to "installations"?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Here](https://www.swtestacademy.com/allure-testng/) :

```
@Test (priority = 0, description=”Invalid Login Scenario with wrong username and password.”)
```

Also, you can add an additional description with @Description annotation:

```
@Description(“Test Description: Login test with wrong username and wrong password.”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I actually needed the `@Title("Installations")` annotation.
It worked perfectly for my needs